# How to write floating point pixel values to a image file with pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to process an image one pixel at a time and the pixel data is coming in 8 bit but ending up floating point.  I'd like to preserve this data in a new image file. It doesn't matter what format tiff or exr...
the below example is just an example. So when I am writing the pixel `pix[i,j] = (float,float,float)`
I get an error expecting `int`.

How do I keep these values float and write a new file?

The other examples I see don't address this problem with writing one pixel at a time.

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

imgIn = Image.open("heightmapSmallLinear.png") # import source image

pix = imgIn.load()
size = imgIn.size

for i in range(size[0]): #loop over all pixels in x
  for j in range(size[1]): # loop over all pixels in y
    pixHSV = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(pix[i,j][0]/255.0,pix[i,j][1]/255.0,pix[i,j][2]/255.0)#rgb pixel color to hsv #convert rgb to hsv
    pix[i,j] = (pixHSV[0],pixHSV[1],pixHSV[2]) # write new pixel

imgIn.save('example.exr')#save image
```

Comment: Pillow doesn't current support EXR format. However see [Writing Your Own Image Plugin](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/writing-your-own-file-decoder.html).

Comment: Overwriting the old pixels won't work, you need to create a new image with the proper pixel format.